# Javascript Regex to convert _xxx_ to [i]xxx[i] ignoring any text between <> (URLs) or `` (code)

Tags: javascript, regex, slack, bbcode

I'm trying to reformat Slack formatting to bbcode and need a little help. Slack does italics like this:

```
_this is italic_ and this isn't
```

My current expression (`/\_([^\_]*)\_/gm`) works but unfortunately picks up underscores in URLs and inside code snippets. Slack formats URLs and code like this:

```
<www.thislink.com|here's a link>
`here's a code snippet`
```

How can I tell regex not to match any underscore pairs inside a link or code snippet? I've been trying negative lookahead and lookbehind but without success.

Comment: I've got this to work for now but I don't really understand how. Could someone explain or tell me why it isn't a valid solution?
_([^_<>`]*)_(?!\S*>)(?!\S*`)

Comment: Not sure you can, you could have this string to parse: `\`\`\`code_1_\`\`\` _italic_ \`\`\`code_2_\`\`\``, how would you parse that? How about temporarely removing links and snippets from the string before parsing for italics?

Answer (score 0):

You need to match and capture what you need and just match what you do not need.

Once you get a match, analyze it and implement the appropriate code logic:

```js
const re = /<[^<>|]*(?:\|[^<>]*)?>|`[^`]*`|_([^_]*)_/g;
const text = "<www.thislink.com|here's a link>\n`here's a code snippet`\n_this is italic_ and this isn't";
console.log( text.replace(re, (m,g) => g !== undefined ? "[i]" + g + "[/i]" : m ) )
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GKq84t/1). *Details*:

- `<[^<>|]*(?:\|[^<>]*)?>` - a `<`, then zero or more chars other than `<`, `>` and `|`, then an optional sequence of a `|` and then zero or more chars other than `<` and `>` and then a `>` char
- `|` - or
- `` `[^`]*` `` - a backtick, zero or more chars other than a backtick and a backtick
- `|` - or
- `_([^_]*)_` - `_`, Group 1: zero or more chars other than `_`, a `_`.